# Why is there a SSL handshake error on certain websites?

Tags: c++, qt, ssl, handshake, qnetworkaccessmanager

Lately I have been reading a book regarding Qt and in the book they try to download the HTML code from a website. Which worked fine for me for almost all websites but there were some websites i couldn't get it to work, I always got the error "SSL handshake error". Are those websites encrypted or am i doing somethign wrong?

code:

```
manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("https://www.google.de/")));
```

for example https://www.google.de/ worked fine for me but when i tried:
https://www.oth-regensburg.de/ i got the SSL handshake error.

Comment: Which version of Qt and OpenSSL are you using?

Comment: Its 5.11.0 I don't know about OpenSSL though

Comment: See if the `sslErrors` signal contains a useful list of errors. Your Qt is new enough to support the ciphers used by the website you mentioned